# Knight can't answer about joker

Tags: liars

If you ask a knight (True) about a Joker's answer (random), then she can't answer because she doesn't know?
Does this give a NaN response or is it not allowed?

I looked at similar questions and couldn't find something directly addressing the problem.
Which is odd because the standard answer to the simplest knight/knave problem (no joker) is to ask what the others response is

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This would depend on the rules of that puzzle, and we're not the Arbiters of Liar Puzzle Rules here.

Answer (score 2):

It could be any of:

- the knight gives a third answer (like "I don't know")
- the knight refuses to answer
- the knight randomly picks what the joker would say in the hypothetical, and answers appropriately
- this type of question is not allowed

It depends on the specific puzzle-setter. There is no universal standard for "knights and knaves" puzzles.